# What is the “prayer” in a claim?

Tags: england-and-wales, legal-terms

A blog refers to certain things not having been pleaded/specified in the “prayer”. What does this refer to?

Comment: By the way, the answer provided is correct, but not illustrative. Here's a typical example:

WHEREFORE, Plaintiffs/Petitioners pray for judgment as follows as to the 
Writ:
1. For the issuance of a peremptory writ of mandate pursuant to Code of 
Civil Procedure section 1085, commanding Defendants, and each of them, 
to permit Petitioners to develop their properties for cultivation, so long as 
they comply with applicable building codes;
2. For Petitioners’ attorneys’ fees and costs incurred in this matter as 
provided by law; and
3. For other such relief as this Court deems proper.

Comment: @A.fm. That would probably be a better as a comment on the answer, but the exmaple doesn't sound like a prayer in England & Wales.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the [Legal Dictionary](https://dictionary.law.com/Default.aspx?selected=1571) includes this definition:

> the specific request for judgment, relief and/or damages at the conclusion of a complaint or petition.